# XCTest Async Function Swift

Tags: swift, xctest, xctestcase, xctestexpectation

i'm quite new to XCTest, i have structured my code in Model, View, Controller

So controller will take data from Model and once got data, Controller will update View.
So i have my Controller and view as follow

Controller:

```
func loadData() {
    Model.provideData { response in
        if response != nil {
            view.refresh()
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
func refresh() {
    isViewLoaded = true
}
```

and here is my XCTest

```
func testLoadData() {
    let sut = Controller()
    let mockView = View()
    mockView.setController(controller: sut)
    controller.loadData()
    /** HERE is the problem, because it is a ASYNC call, i need to wait for the flag is set **/
    XCTAssertTrue(mockView.isViewLoaded, "isViewLoaded equals to true")
}
```

i know i can

```
let expectation = expectation(description: "wait for isViewLoaded set to true")
```

but where should i put the `expectation.fulfill()`?

```
waitForExpectation(timeout: 5, handler: nil)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need to mock the Controller so your test gets the completion handler. Or make your Model testable.

Comment: My aim is to test controller, I can test my Model already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your `loadData` to have a completion handler and hence be able to notify its callers when the async function is complete.

```
func loadData(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    Model.provideData { response in
        if response != nil {
            view.refresh()
        }
        completion()
    }
}
```

And then in your test, do `expectation.fulfill` in the `completion` of `loadData`.

```
func testLoadData() {
    let expectation = expectation(description: "wait for isViewLoaded set to true")
    let sut = Controller()
    let mockView = View()
    mockView.setController(controller: sut)
    controller.loadData {
        expectation.fulfill()
    }
    waitForExpectation(timeout: 5, handler: nil)
    XCTAssertTrue(mockView.isViewLoaded, "isViewLoaded equals to true")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yep I have thought of making my loadData a callback, just thinking if this is best practice? Since I’m quite new to init testing, I’m not sure is it ok?

Comment: This is basically what I said in my comment. (Not a criticism, just telling the OP.) In other words, OP, it is your job to make the controller testable, either itself or a mock version. You could use a dependency injection so that only the testable version provides the callback.

Comment: @wes.i yes, it is best practise for async methods to have a callback. And not just for testing, but in general.